# Graphical problems with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I get graphical problems with VS 2010 were the text editor blanks out sections of the code and docked tool windows do not draw properly.  You can see this in the image below, the Resharper File Structure window does not draw properly.

[Edit 1] This happens when I maximise the window.  The code in the text editor has not refreshed since maximising and the File Structure code window has stayed in the same position horizontally, although it has moved vertically.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

My machine is a Win 7 Ultimate x64 desktop with a Radeon HD6800 driver 8.920.0.0 with twin monitors 1920x1200 main and 1600x1200 secondary.

The problem doesn't always reproduce, you have to run for some time before you see it.  When it appears, it does not affect all open files, generally just one or two.

[image: glitches]

I have the following packages installed into my environment:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Ultimate

Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual F# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01019-532-2002102-70884
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Add Reference Dialog Plus!   1.0
An significantly enhanced Add Reference dialog for managed code projects.

AlignAssignments   1.0
Command for aligning assignments.

AutoBraceComplete   1.0
auto brace complete

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Document Well 2010 Plus   1.0.10916.0
This package provides configurable behavior for the Document Well and its tabs. Please be sure to let us know what you like/dislike about this extension.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2522890)   KB2522890
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2522890.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2529927)   KB2529927
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529927.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2547352)   KB2547352
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547352.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2548139)   KB2548139
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548139.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2549864)   KB2549864
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2565057)   KB2565057
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057.

JetBrains dotTrace Performance 4.5.1   build 4.5.922.8 on 2011-08-03T20:47:06 [Not Loaded]
JetBrains dotTrace Performance 4.5.1 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about dotTrace, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/. Copyright © 2005–2012 JetBrains, Inc.

JetBrains ReSharper 6.1   C# Edition build 6.1.37.86 on 2011-12-20T21:15:24
JetBrains ReSharper 6.1 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2012 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QuickAccess.Package   1.0
Awesome search bar. 

NuGet Package Manager   1.6.21215.9133
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

QuickFind   1.0
Visual Studio 2010 Quick Incremental Find Extension

SQL Server Compact Toolbox   2.6
SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in for Visual Studio 2010.
Adds scripting, import, export, rename, query execution and much more to SQL Server Compact Data Connections.

VistaDB 4 Designer for Visual Studio   4.1.16.1
VistaDB 4 Designer for Visual Studio
For more information see http://www.vistadb.net
Copyright (c) 2010

VisualHG   1.1.5
Mercurial source contol provider.

VSCommands 2010   3.8.0.2
Prevent accidental Drag & Drop in Solution Explorer, Group Items, Locate In Solution, Create Code Contract, Copy/Paste References and many many others!

XtraReports package   1.0
XtraReports package
```

Comment: Are you using Windows 7?  32-bit or 64-bit OS?  Is this system a laptop?  Which graphics chipsest are you using?

Comment: Added to description.

Comment: Do you happen to have VS2008 installed as well?

Comment: No, just VS 2010.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the VS settings to default (`Devenv /ResetSettings`)?  Does it do it in VS Safe Mode (`Devenv /SafeMode`) as well?  Are your Radeon drivers up-to-date?

Comment: @techie007: Drivers are up to date (by Windows Update). Haven't tried running in safe mode or resetting settings as the problem doesn't always reproduce, you have to run for some time before you see it.  Have added this info to the question.

Comment: Did the problem start recently?   If so, try reverting to a previous version of your video driver.

Comment: @Roger - no, I've been seeing it on and off for a long while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled the setting "Enable rich client visual experience" under Environment | General and the problem has not occurred since.